# Can't connet to jdbc while testing all suggested solutions

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to mysql on my laptop. using the code I have pasted below. I have added the *CLASSPATH* containing the full path of the file:

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar
```

and exported it.But I get persistently the mentioned error. Can somebody tell me, please, what I am missing that makes me to get this error message form my machine.

My machine is Fedora core 21, I am trying to execute the code under the user, and not root, and this is the code i am using and of course the static final variables "user" and "password" are not empty strings as they are here:

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages

import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample {
  // JDBC driver name and database URL    
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

   //  Database credentials   
   static final String USER = "";    
   static final String PASS = "";    

   public static void main(String[] args) {    
   Connection conn = null;    
   Statement stmt = null;    
   try{   
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver    
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");        
      //STEP 3: Open a connect ion    
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");    
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);    
      //STEP 4: Execute a query   
      System.out.println("Creating database...");    
      stmt = conn.createStatement();          
      String sql = "CREATE DATABASE STUDENTS";    
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);    
      System.out.println("Database created successfully...");    
   }catch(SQLException se){    
      //Handle errors for JDBC    
      se.printStackTrace();    
   }catch(Exception e){    
      //Handle errors for Class.forName   
      e.printStackTrace();    
   }finally{    
      //finally block used to close resources    
      try{    
         if(stmt!=null)   
            stmt.close();    
      }catch(SQLException se2){   
      }// nothing we can do    
      try{    
         if(conn!=null)    
            conn.close();    
      }catch(SQLException se){    
         se.printStackTrace();   
      }//end finally try    
   }//end try   
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");    
}//end main    
}//end JDBCExample
```

I have really tried to include any related information that i could guess it is related. If more information is needed to answer the question I am willingly ready to provide.

Comment: what is the actual error message. The title looks hand typed

Comment: The database URL needs to include the database name. Why all the blank lines? Step 2 has been unnecessary since 2007. Closing the connection closes the statement and result set.

Comment: This is the actual error message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:19)
Goodbye!

Comment: The error message suggests that the JDBC driver is in fact NOT on the classpath.

Comment: Where should i add then the classpath? can I add it to .my .bachrc file or i should add it somewhere else?

Comment: I added the varibale classpath to my .bashrc file and it worked. Thank you Jan.

Answer (score -2):

the `DB_URL` should set the port and the database name of MySQL.

just like(windows):

```
jdbc\:mysql\://111.202.27.131\:3306/bridgeResultDatabase?characterEncoding\=utf8
```

Here `bridgeResultDatabase`is the mysql database name, it works for me.

Hope it helps.

There are some mistakes above. 
Update(I try in my windows and using root of mysql in Linux):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://192.168.11.52/mysql";
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"root","111111");
    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    String hrappSQL = "CREATE DATABASE testDatabase";
    statement.executeUpdate(hrappSQL);
}
```

And I create the database "testDatabase" successfully in my linux mysql.

Comment: These backslashes are only needed in a properties file.

Comment: So any plan to fix it?

Comment: This does not work. While searching for answer i have undersod that i do not know even my mysql URL. I am trying to understand how to find my mysql URL. I have another question: Is it necessary to be the root in order to connect to mysql database from java?

Comment: Your code works when i use with the root account of mysql.

Comment: Yes. I have used root, and added the variable classpath to my .bashrc file and everything is OK now. Thanks  all.